# Which is the exception raised that gives "ConnectionResetError" in thrift python?

Tags: python, exception, thrift

I'm using thrift with python and at disconnection I currently catch the `TTransportException` in order to attempt a reconnection. This works fine most of the time, but sometimes the error I get is `ConnectionResetError` which is naturally not caught. Now my question is : which exception do I have to catch in order to attempt a reconnection even if I get a `ConnectionResetError`. 
I don't want to simply catch `TException`, or `Exception` but only exceptions caused by a disconnection.

Comment: `ConnectionResetError` is a built-in exception.

Comment: that's weird then, because it doesn't catch my `try catch ConnectionResetError` block

Comment: There could be an other exception with the same name. You should catch all exceptions and inspect yours when it occurs.

Comment: I'll try debugging this when I have the time, but I have not made any exception with already used/common names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you're looking for is `thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransport.Exception`

Transport exceptions are raised when you have connection problems.